# How to make API request using PHP cURL?

Tags: php, api, curl

My request requires a token to make API requests. Here is the cURL code they provide as example:

```
curl -v -L https://api.artsy.net/api/artists/andy-warhol -H 'X-Xapp-Token:myToken'
```

My code:

```
$postdata = array();
$postdata['client_id'] = 'myId';
$postdata['client_secret'] = 'myClient';
$postdata['xapp_token'] = 'myToken';
$cc =  curl_init();
curl_setopt($cc,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($cc,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($cc,CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.artsy.net/api/artists/andy-warhol");
curl_setopt($cc,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postdata);
$result = curl_exec($cc);
echo $result;
```

This should result in a JSON object that looks like:

```
{
  "id": "4d8b92b34eb68a1b2c0003f4",
  "slug": "andy-warhol",
  "created_at": "2010-08-23T14:15:30+00:00",
  "updated_at": "2017-08-25T17:25:51+00:00",
  "name": "Andy Warhol",
  "sortable_name": "Warhol Andy",
  "gender": "male",
  "birthday": "1928",
  "hometown": "Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania",
  "location": "New York, New York",
  "nationality": "American",
//...
```

However it results in this result:

```
{:type=>"other_error", :message=>"405 Not Allowed", "X-Frame-Options"=>"DENY", "X-Robots-Tag"=>"noindex", "Allow"=>"OPTIONS, GET, HEAD"}
```

I'm not too familiar with cURL so I've hit a wall with trying to translate the example code they provide. Any help would be deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using POST

```
curl_setopt($cc,CURLOPT_POST,1);
```

and it looks like the API doesn't allow POST.

> `..."Allow"=>"OPTIONS, GET, HEAD"`

You can check [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404162/is-there-curlopt-postfields-equivalent-for-get-method-in-curl-reqest) for an example of how to use GET instead.

Comment: Yeah, it's probably expecting a `GET` call, and the values as a query string.

Comment: @ceejayoz Ah! Thank you for pointing that out! I replaced `curl_setopt($cc,CURLOPT_POST,1);` with `curl_setopt($cc, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');` and it now returns:
`{"_links":{"location":{"href":"https://api.artsy.net/api/artists/4d8b92b34eb68a1b2c0003f4"}}}`. 

Unfortunately, my new problem is, I'm trying to access the "href" target, but keep getting an error: `Recoverable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string` with 
`$result = curl_exec($cc); $myJson = json_decode($result); echo $myJson->_links;`
Any help on this? Thank you!

Comment: @Sam That new error isn't really related to the original problem you asked about here, so it's probably better to ask a new question about it. However, I'll warn you it's likely to be closed as a duplicate of [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php) so I'd recommend taking a look at that first.

Comment: @Sam I'll tell you, it looks like the URL should be at `$myJson->_links->location->href`. But it looks like the API could return multiple links, so you probably want to iterate `$myJSON->_links` instead. It's a bit much to cover in the comments section.